# Creating a ProgressDialog for loading

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have this snippet from this [site.](http://www.tutorials-android.com/learn/How_to_display_a_progress_dialog_while_computing.rhtml)

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Title", 
"Message", true);
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
   public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      dialog.dismiss();
      }
   };
Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {  
   public void run() {
//
// YOUR LONG CALCULATION (OR OTHER) GOES HERE
//
      handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
      }
   };
checkUpdate.start();
```

I don't fully understand how it fully works other than the fact it creates a new thread for the ProcessDialog to run until process is complete.

I am assuming which of course correct me if I am wrong that this creates a new thread making the existing thread still running which would cause a null value on the .xml items.

My question are

> How would it be possible to run this code without going into a null
>   pointer exception?
>
> Is there another alternate solution to doing something similar to
>   this?

Comment: which line will go to null pointer exception?

Comment: Please provide the stack trace for your NullPointerException.

Comment: Try this one... Use getapplicationcontext() instead of 'this'

Comment: Method is more than a 100 lines long however I can give you that after the threading calculation it goes to a log.i which gives out an input but the string is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More elegant and preferred way of doing this is to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>
    {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(final Object... urls)
        {
           // long calculation

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Object result)
        {
            closeDialog();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            showDialog();
        }
    }

private void closeDialog()
    {
        if (dialog != null)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    private void showDialog()
    {
        if (dialog !=null && !dialog.isShowing())
        {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
            dialog.show();

        }

    }
```

Call it with this line:

```
new DownloadTask().execute();
```

Comment: How do I just make it run with just a single method? I know I require this on the beginning to make it to load more professionally.

Comment: I don`t understand what you mean, you can call new DownloadTask().execute(); as many times as you want..

Comment: Your right sorry I never implemented async task classes in my activities before. 
I am getting this error when I tried adding this code.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

No line given on log cat on where the error could be.

Comment: Mark as resolved please if you got your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905587/system-services-not-available-to-activities-before-oncreate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642580/system-services-not-available-to-activities-before-oncreate-with-fragment-and